# NetSuite SuiteTalk - Retrieve Value String From “SearchColumnSelectField”

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, netsuite, suitetalk

Say you are trying to access a value from SuiteTalk that is returned as type "SearchColumnSelectField":

```
((TransactionSearchRow)row).basic.postingPeriod?[0].searchValue.name
```

*Note: I use postingPeriod as example, but there are many other records that return a "searchValue" of type "RecordRef" that have the same issue.*

This("searchValue.name") will be null, similar to the issue detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496157/netsuite-suitetalk-retrieve-value-string-from-searchcolumnselectcustomfield), but unlike with CustomFields I don't see any documented way of retrieving the lookup values based on the "internalId" of the returned "searchValue"(typically populated). To further complicate things, the returned object does not appear to have a "typeId" specified. It looks something like this:

[image]

So again I wonder, How do I access the text value that I can see from the NetSuite interface from SuiteTalk("searchValue.name")? NetSuite documentation is lacking, clearly in this case it's of [type "period"](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/RecordsBrowser/2012_2/Records/transaction.html), but how does one enumerate that? Or in this case maybe there is a different way to go about retrieving the value?

I've been looking around, but there's not a whole lot written about this. I think this issue is mentioned in [this post](http://www.anyforum.in/question/web-service/netsuite/How-to-get-data-from-saved-search-through-webservice-request/345). Other than that I really can't find anything. I've already checked the API documentation, [here](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3489077.html) and [here](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/schema/enum/recordtype.html?mode=package), it's not much help, I wonder if there is some sort of internal documentation on the subject that I'm not seeing, but from what I've read there's really, [not much](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925643/2912011).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found what appears to be the answer by trying all the get and search methods in SuiteTalk tell I found one that was capable of returning the correct type of results:

```
NetSuiteService nsService = ... //Your NetSuiteService
IEnumerable<TransactionSearchRow> rows = ... //The results of your query

var lookup = nsService.getList(rows.
                Where(a => a.basic.postingPeriod.Any())
                .Select(a =>
                {
                    var value = a.basic.postingPeriod[0].searchValue;
                    value.type = RecordType.accountingPeriod;
                    value.typeSpecified = true;
                    return value;
                })
                .GroupBy(a => a.internalId)
                .Select(a => a.First())
                .ToArray()).readResponse
                .ToDictionary(a => ((AccountingPeriod)a.record).internalId, 
                    a => ((AccountingPeriod)a.record).periodName);

var allPeriods = rows
    .Select(a => a.basic.postingPeriod.Any() ? 
         lookup[a.basic.postingPeriod[0].searchValue.internalId] : "")
    .ToArray();
```

This method is [listed here](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3499748.html), but it doesn't really provided sufficient detail. Also, I'm not sure why:

> Period(Column) = a.basic.postingPeriod(Property) = RecordType.accountingPeriod(Property)  =
>   AccountingPeriod(Type)

I guess one sort of has to guess what each type corresponds too. For period its not too bad, but for some of the other ones it can be a little confusing.

I hope this helps someone else out, for me its been a difficult process. If anyone else has any other solutions I'm still open to suggestions. I'm still not sure this is the most efficient method of data retrieval.